# delay to get data from service to avoid null pointer

Tags: android, android-fragments, service

I found if I try to get data from service the minute when activity was created, it always throw null pointer exception. So how to delay a period of time, show loading animations, then get the data and refresh the view.

I have a service for downloading files tasks, and I want to show the downloading progress in a fragment when the service in working.

I attached the fragment to a activity, which binds the service on its onCreate lifecycle method.

```
 // bind transfer service
    Intent bIntent = new Intent(this, TransferService.class);
    startService(bIntent);
    bindService(bIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "try bind TransferService");
```

But every time I goto the fragment, I got the null pointer exception, it says service is null. But I already bind the service to the activity, why this could happen.

see the method in fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onActivityCreated");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    List<DownloadTaskInfo> infos = mActivity.getTransferService().getAllDownloadTaskInfos();
    adapter = mActivity.getDownloadTasksAdapter(infos);
    transferTasksList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I guess it caused by the service not binded yet when I resume the fragment, so I want to show a loading animation when waiting for the service to get binded, after that, I can set download progress to the listview.

I don`t know how to implement this, does asynctask can do this? show loading animation while waiting for binding and show set the data source when binded.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
error log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.seafile.seadroid2.ui.activity.TransferActivity.getDownloadTaskInfos(TransferActivity.java:244)
        at com.seafile.seadroid2.ui.activity.TransferActivity.getDownloadTasksAdapter(TransferActivity.java:212)
        at com.seafile.seadroid2.ui.fragment.DownloadTasksFragment.onActivityCreated(DownloadTasksFragment.java:30)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1478)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:945)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1102)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1458)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:470)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
```

and the null pointer line 244 in TansferActivity is

```
txService.getAllDownloadTaskInfos();
```

Comment: i am not sure if android supports some specific sol for this, but if i were you, i will add a Callback to the `getAllDownloadTaskInfos()` and i will call that callback from the service, when download is done, so the activity knows that, hides the progressbar, and start processing data...

Comment: maybe I did\`t express the meaning clearly, `getAllDownloadTaskInfos()` method returns all download tasks whose state can be init, transferring and finished. So my meaning is to get the list from service while the files ware transferring because it only make sense to update ui at that point.

Comment: so you need some delay before even calling `getAllDownloadTaskInfos()`? this could not be the reason, you may have a problem in the binding or other issue, however you can use `Thread.slpeep(3000)` inside `try/catch` after bind and before calling the method, i doubt this is the case, but if it works, i will post a better sol for the sleep time, and posting the crash logcat is good idea too

Comment: yeah, I have a problem in binding.From the log I know that every time I stop and resume the activity, it binds the service again. Sometimes it can finished binding before I can `getAllDownloadTaskInfos`, most times it does\`t, that why the null pointer happens, the service is null. So any ideas? thanks so much.

Comment: i am not sure if it's a timing issue, i will post you an answer with some workaround, you need to try it and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you review the Android tutorial about binding to services.

This is an asynchronous process, so you should create a `ServiceConnection` listener and act upon `onServiceConnected()`. In the meanwhile you should present your waiting animation, and only dismiss it when the binding succeeds.

The tutorial with a detailed code snippet is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: But when I modify the code according the article, I got `android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked ` and the error is android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.seafile.seadroid2.ui.activity.TransferActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.seafile.seadroid2.ui.fragment.DownloadTasksFragment$1@41d56050 that was originally bound here

Comment: I have one Activity called `TransferActivity` and two fragments `DownloadTasksFragment` and `UploadTasksFragment`. Before I bind service in activity, now in order to show the load animation, I changed to bind the service in both the activity and the two fragment. any idea?

Comment: You should bind the service once in your Activity, and then notify the Fragments via a custom listener.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure about this, but give it a try.

we need to wait until the service is not null, so

the code should be

```
while(txService == null){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(200);
        Log.i("TAG","sleep for binding ...")
    }catch(Execeptio e){
        e.printStacktrace()
    }
}//while loop
txService.getAllDownloadTaskInfos();
```

but be careful if this is not the case (wait did not solve) the app will be in an infinite loop
and you have to force close it, you can see in Logs how many times the sleep occurs, so you will know  when txService is not null anymore.

P.S: if you have a specific TAG for log, just use it instead of `"TAG"` at `Log.i()`